# Why val declaration doesn't follow scala constants naming convention?

Tags: scala, coding-style, constants, naming-conventions

In Scala val is used for creating constants and the naming convention for Scala Constants is to use UpperCamelCase convention. (https://docs.scala-lang.org/style/naming-conventions.html#constants-values-variable-and-methods)

A generalization for this rule should be all vals should be in UpperCamelCase.

i.e. if a variable is declared using val keyword its name should be in UpperCamelCase. However I see examples on Scala's website exploiting this rule.

What am I missing here?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Put simply:

A constant only has one value while the program is running. It is either fixed at compile time, e.g. `Pi`, `HoursInDay`, or is an immutable value inside a top-level `object`.

A `val` is an immutable variable. It cannot be changed once it is set, but it may be set to different values each time the containing code is called.

Comment: Thanks Tim. This makes sense but when would declaring a val inside a class/trait benefit? What's the use case for having a val inside a class/trait? If we need a constant we can also declare it inside the companion object of a class. Why do we want to have a functionality which allows for different values of a val each time the containing code is called?

Comment: It makes sense when the `val` is computed from the parameters of the class. So I can say `case class Rectangle(width: Int, height: Int) { val area = width*height }` and `area` does not change once it is computed, but different instances of `Rectangle` will have different values for `area` so it isn't a "constant" and can't be in the companion object.

Answer (score 1):

Coding style suggests `final` constants to be uppercased:

> if the member is **final**, immutable and it belongs to a package object
>   or an object, it may be considered a constant

For example, note how `scala.math.PI` is defined as `final`:

```
@inline final val Pi = java.lang.Math.PI
```

`val`s inside objects are final in the sense they cannot be overridden so the following makes sense even though `MyConstant` it is not explicitly declared `final`:

```
object Container {
  val MyConstant = ...
}
```

If the `val` is not final, the style suggest lower case naming.

Comment: In the given example for Scala Constants Naming Convention (https://docs.scala-lang.org/style/naming-conventions.html#constants-values-variable-and-methods) they didn't use final and yet they used UpperCamelCase - 
`
object Container {
  val MyConstant = ...
}
`

As per your explanation I think it should be 

`
object Container {
  final val MyConstant = ...
}
`

Or

`
object Container {
  val myConstant = ...
}
`

Comment: `val`s inside objects are final in the sense they cannot be overridden.

Answer (score 1):

`val` in Scala is not **only** for defining **Constants**, it's also for defining **Values**.
So, as Scala documentation states at https://docs.scala-lang.org/style/naming-conventions.html#constants-values-variable-and-methods :

For defining **Constants** you should use `UpperCamelCase` style where we tell these items *Constant* when:

If the member is **final**, **immutable** and it belongs to a **package object** or an **object**, it may be considered a constant.

For example:

```
object Container {
  val MyConstant = ...
}
```

While **method**, **value** and **variable** names should be in `lowerCamelCase` style like:

```
val myValue = ...
def myMethod = ...
var myVariable = ...
```